# How to restrict values in a filter in a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Suppose I have a pivot table and I have 2 filtering criteria (state and zip code). Suppose for my first filter, state, I select CA. I want to only see zip codes that are in CA, in my second filter, zip code. However, I see all zip codes in the United States in my second filter, zip code. I am using Microsoft Excel 2007. Is there a way to correct this so I only see the zip codes that are conditional on the state I select?

Comment: No I have State and ZIp Code in the Report Filter. CA is simply one possible value of state.

Comment: I don't want to move it to ROWS. I want Zip Code to be part of the filter. I just want a 'hierarchical filter' in which the values for the filter below are contingent on the values for the filter above it. In this case, if I select State as CA, I only want to see zip codes associated with CA in my Zip Code filter.